# Log4j2 doesn't see configuration xml

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j, log4j2

Probably, I searched all Internet, but I must miss something.

I configure Log4j2 and Commons-logging according to documentation. I add `log4j2.xml`, but its configuration has no impact of application output. I looks like Log4j doesn't read this file. Here is my config:

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <log4j2.version>2.3</log4j2.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**\src\main\resources\log4j2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="TRACE">

    <Properties>
        <Property name="filename">fileName</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="Pattern Pattern %d{DEFAULT} %-5level %t : %logger{1} - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile"
                     fileName="${filename}.log"
                     filePattern="${filename}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{DEFAULT} %-5level %t : %logger{1} - %m%n"/>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.mydomain" level="TRACE"/>
        <Root level="TRACE">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**In any class - for example class A**

```
private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(A.class);
```

Application has `main()` function, so could be run by IDE or by mvn exec:java.

**Problem:**

Logging is working - but with default way.

As you can see in `log4j2.xml` file I change levels to `TRACE` and in pattern I type: `Pattern Pattern` to check if log4j2 is using my custom configuration.

No `logger.trace()` appears. No text `Pattern Pattern`. No error/warning from log4j in console.

Please help, and tell me what I made wrong?

**EDIT:**

@BrunoMarcoVisioli told me to use `org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager` instead of `LogFactory`. So I add new logger in `main()` method:

```
private static final Logger logger_new = LogManager.getLogger(CalculationApp.class);
```

And logging through this `logger_new` works fine and so I set `TRACE` level, I see also some logs at application startup, first:

```
Starting configuration XmlConfiguration[location=target\classes\log4j2.xml]
```

But logging through `LogFactory` still doesn't work.

Comment: Is `\src\main\resources\` in your application's classpath?

Comment: @Bruno Marco Visioli: Yes. Earlier in that directory was a log4j.properties file which configures older Log4j. Moreover when I make `jar` the file log4j2.xml is inside. Is it sufficient proof?

Comment: If it's possible, try using `org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager` instead of LogFactory from commons-logging, even if it should work togeter.

Comment: @BrunoMarcoVisioli Great hint - now I see such error: `ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.` But still I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: @BrunoMarcoVisioli Wait wait... I notice very strange behavior - I will describe it In EDIT in question.

Comment: I see that the `log4j-jcl` is missing from your POM, try to include it, it's the bridge dependency.

Comment: @BrunoMarcoVisioli Thank you VERY much. Your suggestion is great. After add `log4j-jcl` everything works great. Please put an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the `log4j-jcl` dependency to your POM, it'll work as bridge between commons-logging and log4j2.

Answer (score -2):

Its usually a problem with where the file is located..

From the documentation

By default, Log4j looks for a configuration file named log4j2.xml (not log4j.xml) in the classpath.

Comment: I use `log4j2.xml`. This is included in question.